# How to debug a solution with multiple projects in Qt creator

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

I have a client-server solution and i am not able to debug both of them in the same time.

1. I put breakpoint in the main of App1
2. I put breakpoint in the main of App2
3. I start in debug App1
4. I hit the breakpoint in main of App1 
   Issue:
5. The breakpoint from the main of App2 is not hit
   How to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to use one instance of QtCreator to debug two executables? I think this is not possible since you have to attach two debugger instances to two different executables. But you might use two instances of QtCreator to solve your problem (haven't tried this before).